# Pod init & Pod install Failure - iOS Xcode beta 14.0

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods

I have issue while I tried to do pod init or pod install,
getting following errors.
Using Xcode 14 beta & OS version 12.4. Since after Xcode and OS update have issues,

```
pod install

Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
Analyzing dependencies

[!] Smart quotes were detected and ignored in your Podfile. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Users/azeemazeez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Users/azeemazeez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/azeemazeez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Users/azeemazeez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:228:in `initialize_from_file': [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56). (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/azeemazeez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1190:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1189:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1189:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1184:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:106:in `analyze'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Users/azeemazeez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I have several solutions like,

```
uninstall cocoa pods and reinstalled.
```

I tried brew update as well

```
brew update
brew install fastlane
fastlane install_plugins
```

None of them worked out for me. Still getting above errors.

Comment: Try with pod deintegrate, pod install.

Comment: this helped, but I have changed Xcode beta to Xcode!

Comment: Just an FYI, often for open source projects you might find more success for stuff like this by creating an issue on CocoaPods GitHub page.

Answer (score 30):

I changed the Project Format from Xcode 14.0 to Xcode 13.0 and it worked for me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me

Comment: I was stuck without any solutions...this is the only one that worked for me! thank you

Answer (score 7):

First run in the terminal of your project

```
sudo gem update xcodeproj
```

Then run

```
pod init
```

Answer (score 2):

Change project compatibility to 13.0 - worked for me :)

[right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNQZR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This may be the issue:

```
Smart quotes were detected and ignored in your Podfile.
```

Try to check your `Podfile` in some text editor like vscode, vim or nano and substitute all the quotes with new ones

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to fix the issue in Xcode beta, tried to change the path `sudo xcode-select` `cocoapods uninstalled and reinstalled`, `gem installed, brew` everything but nothing worked.

Then changed the version `Xcode beta 14.0 to Xcode 13.4.`

After that tried,

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

then pod deintegrated

```
pod deintegrate
```

finally

```
pod install
```

then started working...

Answer (score 0):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"] = "Your Team ID"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This post_install script in podfile fixed it. As it seems setting the own developer team is necessary. Replace Your Team ID with the TeamID of your project.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me for xcode 14 beta.

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

**XCODE 14.2 WITH M1Chip and M2Chip working 100%**

I faced a similar issue after 3 to 4 hours tried i found the this soultion , by default system ruby version is being used, we need to bypass it and then continue with cocoa pods.

1.Install ruby using homebrew

**brew install ruby**

By default, binaries installed by gem will be placed into: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin

You may want to add this to your PATH.

ruby is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local, because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have ruby first in your PATH run (and replace user_name with your username):

**echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/user_name/.bash_profile**
For compilers to find ruby you may need to set:

**export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"**

**export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"**

Follow the instructions to set PATH. Replace user_name with your username

**echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/user_name/.bash_profile**

**echo 'export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"' >> ~/.bash_profile**

**echo 'export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"' >> ~/.bash_profile**

**source ~/.bash_profile**

Check your path

**ruby -v**

Then we will get this one in the terminal

ruby 3.1.1p18 (2022-02-18 revision 53f5fc4236) [x86_64-darwin20]

**user@MacBook-Air ios % which ruby**

/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby

That's it, ruby version is all set Install cocoa pods then you are good to go

**sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods**

Later add your project target and pod init

it works fine